# Failed To Load Resource Error

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble viewing 3 different background-image .jpg files through one thumbnailFilePath in javascript. The HTML and CSS coding does recognize all of the files correctly, but the background images will not load into a browser. Therefore, you can not view these images. On the other hand, the browser does recognize to see the javascript videocaption text and the play_icon.png image files correctly.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a.videoLink').each(function(){ 

    var thumbnailFilePath = 'video/'+$(this).attr('videofile')+'.jpg';
    var videoCaption = $(this).attr('videocaption');

    $(this).css('background-image','url('+thumbnailFilePath+')'); 
    $(this).html('<div class="caption">'+videoCaption+'</div><img src="../images/play_icon.png" class="play"/>');

  });

});
```

Comment: Your line $(this).html replaces anything the $(this).css does. You should add the .css to the end of that line, if the intent is for the link to be replaced with the div. Otherwise, use .append or a similar construct to add the div to the link without removing the link (and the background image)

Comment: @CrisCarew: I'm not sure what you mean. `$(this).html(...)` replaces the *contents* of the `this` element. (In non-DOM terms, it's like `innerHTML`, not `outerHTML`.) I've just tested, and something like `$('div').css('background-color', '#DEF'); $('div').html('text');` will successfully set every `div` on the page to be the word `text` on a light-blue background. So is there something specific about the OP's code that makes you say that the `.html` will supersede the `.css`?

Comment: No, just confusing `.html(...)` with `.replace(...)`. However, I am wondering if perhaps it's not a simple css issue. Is the a.videoLink a block level element, or large enough to display the background image. If you inspect the element (using IE developer, Firebug, Chrome Inspector..) does it have the correct background image style?

Comment: @CrisCarew: I double checked the css and the display is block... a.videoLink {
 display: block;
 height: 90px;
 width: 120px;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}

Comment: Here is the HTML for one of the .jpg... <a class="videoLink" videowidth="120" videoheight="90" videofile="bruce_waltke" videocaption="Bruce Waltke" style="background-image: url(file:///C:/apache/htdocs/Truth%20Web%20Site/include/video/bruce_waltke.jpg); "><div class="caption">Bruce Waltke</div><img src="../images/play_icon.png" class="play"></a>

Comment: In view of the Chrome Inspector the JavaSrcipt, HTML, and CSS see the .jpg files, but the .jpg image is broken.

Comment: Hello All! I figured it out. I wanted to thank you for your support. I will post the answer in the answers post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your video directory is not located in the same directory like your javascript file with this code? Otherwise use a additional slash in front of "video", if it is in the root:

```
var thumbnailFilePath = '/video/'+$(this).attr('videofile')+'.jpg';
```

Comment: Chris! I wish adding a forward slash would have solved it. Great idea! However, when I was having troubles viewing the play_icon.png file, I moved the class="play" to the end of the $(this).html code. In this way, I was able to view the image file in the browser. But when the class="play" was in front of the img src= code I could not view the image file.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of the following attribute?

```
.attr('videofile')
```

Did you give attention to the file extension? (maybe result is: myvideofile.mpg.jpg)

Comment: Hello Chris! If I do not have a .mpg file at this moment the .attr should still pick up the .jpg file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that my .jpg files must have the identical file name as my HTML source code. The videofile="bruce_waltke" must have the same .jpg name. So my .jpg file was named bruce waltke.jpg with no underscore in-between. So the .jpg was initially saved as bruce waltke.jpg but it is now saved as bruce_waltke.jpg....So the image file was broken but its now fixed.

Comment: <div class="video_gallery_container">
 <a class="videoLink" videowidth="120" videoheight="90" videofile="bruce_waltke" videocaption="Bruce Waltke"></a>

Comment: I also had to change the JavaScript -FROM- var thumbnailFilePath = 'video/'+$(this).attr('videofile')+'.jpg'; -TO- var thumbnailFilePath = '../video/'+$(this).attr('videofile')+'.jpg';